# Inserting back slash between left and right braces

Tags: equations, braces

I want to write (Natural number set) \ (singleton $n$). How do I write this? The code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \mathbb{N}\\{n\}
\end{document
```

But `\mathbb{N}\\{n\}` does not seem to work.

Comment: There is `\setminus`, or `\smallsetminus` (the latter requires `amssymb`).

Comment: @campa  I was looking for `\setminus` .